# GetSystemService DOWNLOAD_SERVICE in non activity

Tags: android, android-activity

In my simple method in non activity class, I am using code:

```
mgr=(DownloadManager)mContext.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
```

in non activity class, my constructor looks like:

```
public Download23(Context context){
    this.mContext=context;
}
```

But compilator won't accept DOWNLOAD_SERVICE string. Do you know how to solve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use

```
(DownloadManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
```

Comment: this helps to access the mAct as an activity so one can call getSystemService. Just need to write mAct.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE to also make this accessible.

Comment: @hotveryspicy: I have one question Means we need to create Activity class in NonActivityclass? like: public static class Activtyclass extends Activity{
 
 public static Activity mAct;

 public void onCreate()
 {
 mAct=this;
 }
} in Broadcastreceiver class. is that right?

Comment: This creates a memory leak.

Answer (score 13):

Instead you could just write

```
(DownloadManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
```

That would compile.

`DOWNLOAD_SERVICE` is a constant of Context class.