# How to replace old document with new document in mobile storage using download manager?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-sqlite, android-download-manager

My question is I need to use sync function after every 15 minutes, So what I want is, I will send doc_id to web server and server will return a new doc_Id with some fields, what i want is to replace old document with new one.

my code:

```
 public void Updatefile(String Doc_Id)
{
    try
    {
        SoapObject Subfolderrequest = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, UPDATE_FILE_METHOD);
        Subfolderrequest.addProperty("DocumentID", Doc_Id);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Subfolderrequest);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_UPDATE_FILE , envelope);
        SoapObject SubfolderResponse = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();  
        Log.i("SubFolders", SubfolderResponse.toString());  
        for(int i=0; i < SubfolderResponse.getPropertyCount(); i++)
        {
            SoapObject SingleSubFolder = (SoapObject)SubfolderResponse.getProperty(i);      
            ID = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(0).toString();
            fileLongName = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(1).toString();
            UserFileName = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(2).toString();
            url = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(3).toString();
            fileExtension = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(4).toString();
            lastModifiedDate = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(5).toString();
            SubjectType = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(6).toString();

        }
        if(IsUpdated==true){
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setTitle(UserFileName);
            // in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
                {
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                }
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/Downloads", UserFileName);
                    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    manager.enqueue(request);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }   
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        Log.i("Hi", "Exception");
    }
}
```

What I want is, i will pass id's one by one and If document has been updated then it will check with Boolean value "isupdated" from web server, if "isUpdated" will be true then It will replace document otherwise not. Please let me know how to replace the document with existing one. 
Also I am calling method in Broadcast receiver, which is giving error in line :
:    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

```
 //error in getSystemService... thank you. :)
```

Comment: use context.getsystemservice

Comment: use it this.getContext().getSystemService

Comment: no it is not working...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411873/getsystemservice-download-service-in-non-activity

Comment: hi @stackoverflow, Means I need to create a Activity class in Broadcast receicver class, right? Activity variable can use that getSystemService.

Comment: in Brodcast u are using [public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)].............use this context for systemservice

Comment: @stackoverflow:Thanks, Please let me know, Ho to replace old document with new document.

Comment: nothing, just get the name of that file and create new file with same at same position data will be changed , lol,

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29702/discussion-between-stackoverflow-and-shiva)